# Coiling of chromatids during cell division

Tags: cell-biology, chromosome, meiosis, mitosis

What is exactly coiling of chromosomes?
I just heard about the names i.e paranemic, plectonemic, orthostichious, anorthospiral.
I have ecaxtly no idea of what phenomenon is this.
Also what type of coiling occurs during meiosis and mytosis type of cell division.
Could it be explained in detail....?